# What is the need of using two cells when one can equivalently use another cell of high e.m.f?

Tags: electricity

For instance, suppose in torch, these two cells are present in series.

[image]

Then, $V_c-Ir_2+E_2-Ir_2+E_1=V_a\implies V_a-V_c=(E_2+E_1)-I(r_1+r_2)=(5+5)-1(1+1)=8$.
The potential difference between $a$ and $c$ is $8\, V$.

Equivalently, we could use another cell of e.m.f $10\, V$ and internal resistance $2\, Ω$. That would also serve the same purpose. So, why we use two cells, in practice, instead of one?

Comment: What chemistry do you propose to use to achieve a 10 V cell? Is it more or less expensive than the common cell types on the market? Is its energy density more or less than other cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for the same reason that you open a packet of biscuits and eat three of them, rather than looking for a single biscuit three times larger. Since different appliances have differing voltage requirements, it is easier to satisfy them by having a few standardised batteries at certain voltages, and using multiples of them, than by manufacturing batteries at lots of different voltages.